# Different results when running coxphf into a loop function and as separate analysis

Tags: function, cox-regression

I'm trying to run an Cox-regression using the Firth penalized likelihood. When I run the univariate analysis as a separate analysis I got a different result than when I run that into a function to apply to several columns. Summarizing my data:

```
OS_months <- c(33.6, 52.8, 7.2, 18, 80.4, 109.2, 16.8, 108, 2.4, 51.6, 33.6, 
38.4, 7.2, 12, 144, 2.4, 68.4, 58.8, 52.8, 142.8, 42, 8.4, 115.2, 
10.8, 103.2, 66, 18, 141.6, 66, 144, 13.2, 64.8, 38.4, 20.4, 
81.6, 86.4, 105.6, 75.6, 51.6, 115.2, 21.6, 201.6, 62.4, 81.6, 
157.2, 109.2, 170.4, 44.4, 108, 40.8)

OS_status <-  c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)

TSPAN6 <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0)

HR <- data.frame(OS_months, OS_status, TSPAN6)
```

Running the analysis as separate analysis.

```
fit=coxphf(Surv(OS_months,OS_status)~TSPAN6,data=HR)
fit
```

Result

```
coxphf(formula = Surv(OS_months, OS_status) ~ TSPAN6, data = HR)
Model fitted by Penalized ML
Confidence intervals and p-values by Profile Likelihood 

           coef se(coef) exp(coef) lower 0.95 upper 0.95    Chisq          p
TSPAN6 1.801352 1.051748  6.057834   1.078865   62.16828 4.200166 0.04042002

Likelihood ratio test=4.200166 on 1 df, p=0.04042002, n=50
```

Now into a created function.

```
gene<-function(x){
  fit=coxphf(Surv(OS_months,OS_status)~x,data=HR)
}

a<-lapply(HR[3],FUN=gene)
a
```

Now the result is:

```
$TSPAN6
coxphf(formula = Surv(OS_months, OS_status) ~ x, data = HR)
Model fitted by Penalized ML
Confidence intervals and p-values by Profile Likelihood 

       coef  se(coef) exp(coef) lower 0.95 upper 0.95     Chisq        p
x 0.7413234 0.9106665  2.098711  0.4052701    12.6725 0.8079772 0.368719

Likelihood ratio test=0.8079772 on 1 df, p=0.368719, n=50
```

Can you telling me what is happening here? I will thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to this field, and I tried your code. I thought the problem occurs in the origin dataset instead of running in a loop. Since

```
1) coxphf(formula = Surv(OS_months, OS_status) ~ TSPAN6, data = HR)
```

and

```
2) coxphf(formula = Surv(OS_months, OS_status) ~ HR$TSPAN6, data = HR)
```

give different results. 2) returns the same result as your loop result.

Also, I tried the example data provided by coxphf():

```
time<-c(1,2,3,4)
cens<-c(1,1,1,0)
x<-c(1,1,0,1)
sim<-cbind(time,cens,x)
sim<-data.frame(sim)
coxphf(sim, formula=Surv(time,cens)~x)

gene <- function(var){
+ fit=coxphf(Surv(time,cens)~var, data=sim)
+ return(fit)
+ }
gene(var=x)
```

The results return same as listed below:

```
coxphf(formula = Surv(time, cens) ~ x, data = sim)
Model fitted by Penalized ML
Confidence intervals and p-values by Profile Likelihood 

   coef se(coef) exp(coef) lower 0.95 upper 0.95    Chisq     p
x -0.05065785 1.223583 0.9506039  0.1182198    10.9519 0.002226143 0.9623682
Likelihood ratio test=0.002226143 on 1 df, p=0.9623682, n=4


coxphf(formula = Surv(time, cens) ~ var, data = sim)
Model fitted by Penalized ML
Confidence intervals and p-values by Profile Likelihood 

    coef se(coef) exp(coef) lower 0.95 upper 0.95     Chisq    p 
var -0.05065785 1.223583 0.9506039  0.1182198    10.9519 0.002226143 0.9623682
Likelihood ratio test=0.002226143 on 1 df, p=0.9623682, n=4
```